# Resolve a promise before state changes UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I am using ui-router and ui-router extras

```
$scope.$on('$transitionStart', function (e, $transition$) {
    var params = {id:1};
    factory.webService(params)
        .success(function (data) {
            if (data.d == "Expired") {//Inspects the application session
                //Stops the state request and sents you to the login screen
                e.preventDefault();
                location.href = "login.html";
            }
            else if (data.d == "NotAllowed") {
                //Stops the state request and keeps you on the state you already are
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                //Proceed to load the requested state
            }
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
            alert(data.Message);
        });
});
```

I need to resolve the success part before the $stateChangeStart is loaded and can't figure out how to do it.

Is there any way of achieving this?

EDIT

So I have my code like this

```
.state('myState', {
        url: "/myState",
        templateUrl: 'views/template.html',
        controller: 'ctrlTemplate',
        viewId: 99,
        resolve: {
            fn: function ($stateParams, myFactory) {
                myFactory.checkSession({viewId:99})
                .then(function onSuccess(response) {
                    var data = response.data;
                    if (data.d == "Expired") {
                        throw "Expired";
                    }
                    else if (data.d == "NotAllowed") {
                        throw "NotAllowed";
                    } else {
                        //RETURN to chain data
                        return data;
                        //Proceed to load the requested state
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (response) {
                    //e.preventDefault();
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

The $http `.then` function is still resolving AFTER `$stateChangeStart` and `$transitionStart` happens and the new state is already loading. I can see it happening in the browser console debugger

Plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i need to wait for the $http response and catch it on the `.success` function

The `.success` method [(deprecated and now removed from AngularJS 1.6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339) is not capable of rejecting a promise, but the `.then` method is capable of *converting* a success to a rejection:

```
var promise = factory.webService(params)
    //.success(function (data) {
    .then( function onSuccess(response) {
        var data = response.data;
        if (data.d == "Expired") {
            //THROW to create a rejected promise
            throw "Expired";
            /*
            //Inspects the application session
            //Stops the state request and sents you to the login screen
            e.preventDefault();
            location.href = "login.html";
            */
        }
        else if (data.d == "NotAllowed") {
            //THROW to create a rejected promise
            throw "NotAllowed";
            /*
            //Stops the state request and keeps you on the state you already are
            e.preventDefault();
            */
        } else {
            //RETURN to chain data
            return data;
            //Proceed to load the requested state
        }
    })
    //.error(function onError(data, status) {
    .catch( function(response) {
        var data = response.data;
        var status = response.status;
        alert(data.Message);
        //THROW to chain rejection
        throw data.Message;
    });
});
```

By using either a `return` or `throw` statement, a new derived promise is created from the response resolved from either the `.then` or `.catch` methods of the httpPromise.

When the resolver function of a ui-router state gets a rejected promise, the state change is aborted.

---

### UPDATE

> So I have my code like this ...
>
> ```
>     //ERRONEOUS
>     resolve: {
>         fn: function ($stateParams, myFactory) {
>             myFactory.checkSession({viewId:99})
>             .then(function onSuccess(response) {
>                 var data = response.data;
>                 if (data.d == "Expired") {
>                     throw "Expired";
>                 }
> ```
>
> I can't understand why the throw doesn't trigger the $stateChangeError.

The resolver function needs to *return* the promise to the router:

```
    resolve: {
        fn: function ($stateParams, myFactory) {
          //vvvvvv RETURN the promise
            return myFactory.checkSession({viewId:99})
            .then(function onSuccess(response) {
                var data = response.data;
                if (data.d == "Expired") {
                    throw "Expired";
                }
```

When a function omits a `return` statement, the function returns a value of `undefined`. In that case the router considers it a success with a value of `undefined`.

Also the `.catch` method is erroneous

> ```
>     //ERRONEOUS   
>           })
>             .catch(function (response) {
>                 //e.preventDefault();
>             });
> ```

When the `.catch` method's rejection handler omits a `return` (or `throw`) statement, the function returns a value of `undefined`. This will *convert* the rejection to a successful promise that resolves with a value of `undefined`.

```
      //CORRECT   
            })
            .catch(function (response) {
                //THROW to chain rejection
                throw response;
                //e.preventDefault();
            });
```

The rule of thumb for functional programming is -- **always return something**.

In the case of promise success and rejection: always `return` or `throw` something.

Comment: Hi georgeawg, thanks to Tome and you I managed to get the response before the state change but now I can't understand why the throw doesn't trigger the $stateChangeError

Comment: The resolver function is not returning the derived promise. See additional answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is more elegant way of doing this: [resolve by ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)

Example:

```
$stateProvider.state('users.profile', {
  url: '/:id',
  templateUrl: 'views/users.profile.html',
  controller: 'UsersController',
  resolve: {
    user: function($stateParams, UserService) {
      return UserService.find($stateParams.id);
    },
    tasks: function(TaskService, user) {
      return user.canHaveTasks() ?
        TaskService.find(user.id) : [];
    }
  }
});
```

Please read the following article on [Advanced routing and resolves](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/advanced-routing-and-resolves-a2fcbf874a1c#.6sz68ih73) for more details.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the factory returns a $http so i need to wait for the $http response and catch it on the success function maybe I am not understanding the page

Comment: @ChildGG, just inject your factory in some `data` in the **resolve** object, as `UserService` in the example. After that just **return** the same implementation that you have assigned to the promise variable in your question.

Comment: @ChildGG glad to help. Please vote and accept my answer if helped. Cheers!